Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table when reading DataTable with rows similar to above it
I'm reading logs that are tab, or comma, or semicolon delimited, and reading them into a DataTable, but once I added the multiple delimiters, I get the error message (when read records, not headers):

System.ArgumentException: Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.

static DataTable ReadDataTable(string filePath)
{
    var reader = ReadAsLines(filePath);
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    int i = 0;

    //this assumes the first record is filled with the column names
    var headers = reader.First().Split('\t',',',';'); 
    foreach (var header in headers)
        dataTable.Columns.Add(header);

    var records = reader.Skip(1);
    foreach (var record in records)
    {
        dataTable.Rows.Add(record.Split('\t', ',', ';' )); //error here
        i++;
    }

    return dataTable;
}

The first file I read is tab delimited (each file is delimited with one delimiter, not multiple), and it doesn't have an issue until line 662, which looks the same as the lines around it:
StartTime           EndTime             Day ElapsedHMS  Status  NewVersionString    VersionFile SourceControlComment    Label   ErrorDescription    AdditionalInformation
05/28/2015 17:51:38                 340.2015.0528.139   \\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\Retail\RetailVersion.cs   34000.2015.0528.139 - Automated version number update.          
... that was first line, and following is lines 661, 662, 663
12/20/2015 18:30:23                 342.2015.122.1  \\view\Build_Developer\R\RetailVersion.cs   342.2015.1220.81 - Automated version number update.         
12/20/2015 18:30:32                 342.2015.122.1  \\view\Build_Developer\R\Version.cs 34200.2015.1220.81 - Automated version number update.           
12/20/2015 18:30:44                 342.2015.122.1  \\view\Build_Developer\R\P\E\CommonCode\RetailVersion.h 342.2015.122.1 - Automated version number update.

        

I'm not sure why the error message is saying the row has more columns than the other rows, since the tabs seem to be the same. I'm not sure if I need to just specify one delimiter since each table has one delimiter type. I can't store these delimiters in my xml file that I also read, so I'm not sure how to obtain what delimiter the table has.
I looked at these links and it's not the same question:
array longer than number of columns in table
convert from string to char for split - I also tried using double quotes but it needed to be char[] which I tried but it didn't fix it
input array longer than number of columns in table - different table
function for reading delimited lines into table
Adding screen shot showing special characters:

I added a writeline, and it's the line in the file with the time of: 12/21/2015 17:31:16

Probably this line has some extra \t somewhere

Assign the result of the split to a separate variable before adding it to the table and add exception handling around the Rows.Add when this throws check the respective row for unexpected splits

I already added int i to count what row it has the error and looking at the file with the characters showing, it's the same as ones above it

I added a writeline as well and it errors out on the line with time 12/21/2015 17:31:16   , but the tabs match the one above it

I finally figured it out.
I followed these ideas
get first x lines of file
find delimiter
And came up with this (detect delimiter in first line/header and use that instead of stating all possibilities when creating DataTable):
private static readonly char[] SeparatorChars = { ';', '\t', ',' };

public static char DetectSeparator(string filePath)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadLines(filePath).Take(1).ToArray();
    return DetectSeparator(lines);
}

public static char DetectSeparator(string[] lines)
{
    var q = SeparatorChars.Select(sep => new
    { Separator = sep, Found = lines.GroupBy(line => line.Count(ch => ch == sep)) })
        .OrderByDescending(res => res.Found.Count(grp => grp.Key > 0))
        .ThenBy(res => res.Found.Count())
        .First();

    return q.Separator;
}

static DataTable ReadDataTable(string filePath)
{
    char delimiter = DetectSeparator(filePath);
    var reader = ReadAsLines(filePath);
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    int i = 0;

    //this assumes the first record is filled with the column names
    var headers = reader.First().Split(delimiter); //split on tab, comma, semicolon
    foreach (var header in headers)
        dataTable.Columns.Add(header);

    var records = reader.Skip(1);
    foreach (var record in records)
    {
        dataTable.Rows.Add(record.Split(delimiter)); //split on tab, comma, semicolon
        //var tmp = record.Split('\t', ',', ';');
        //dataTable.Rows.Add(tmp); //split on tab, comma, semicolon
        i++;
    }

    return dataTable;
}


@derpirscher I also tried what you suggested which is commented out above and it did show the columns weren't being found correctly, as the error message indicated.  Thanks for helping to check that.
